# exception in executing aggrigate query in spring-Hibernate example

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

```
   String SQL_QUERY ="select avg(RATING_NUMBER) From RatingModel where PRODUCT_FK='"+productId+"'";
       Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);//<--exception
        List list = query.list();
        System.out.println("Average" + list.get(0));
```

**Exception is**

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$AvgFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$AvgFunction.render(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.SqlGenerator.endFunctionTemplate(SqlGenerator.java:220)

**I also do this**
but same exception occur

double avg=((Double)         session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY ).uniqueResult()).doubleValue();

Comment: createQuery() expects an HQL query, not a SQL query. HQL uses entities and their fields, not tables and columns. You should also lean about query parameters: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and will fail as soon as there is a quote in the productId.

Comment: the datatype of  productId is String

Comment: And my car is grey. How is that relevant?